# Feathersjs socketio how to correctly set params.route?

Tags: feathersjs, feathers-hook

I have a Feathersjs API which using REST can serve a GET request to a URL like `http://server.com/service-name/:fieldName` where `fieldName` has a string value. The API assigns the value of `fieldName` to `params.query`.

While developing a React Native app, I am trying to make the same request using feathers socketio client. The request looks like this:

```
return this.app.service('service-name/:fieldName').find({
  query:{fieldName='value'}
}).then(response => {
  console.log('data from server', response.data); // ignore this console format
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

The request above makes it to the server, but the value of `fieldName` is either `undefined` or some other unwanted value because the server returns an **empty result set**. I have also read that the [setSlug hook](https://feathers-plus.github.io/v1/feathers-hooks-common/#setslug) would be an option, but I am not sure how to do it.

Can someone please help me resolve this issue by sending the real value of `fieldName` in the request to the server?

[**Edit**]
After checking the logs on the API server, I found out that a REST API request has the correct `params.route` object:

```
object(9) {
    ["query"] => object(0) {}
    ["route"] => object(1) {
        ["fieldName"] => string(5) "value"
    }
    ...
```

The `params.route` is empty with the socketio request:

```
object(9) {
    ["query"] => object(0) {}
    ["route"] => object(0) {}
    ["connection"] => object(6) {
        ["provider"] => string(8) "socketio"
        ["payload"] => object(1) {
            ["userId"] => number(3)
        }
    ...
```

While I'm relieved to know where the problem is, would anyone please tell me how to correctly set `params.route` in React Native using a socketio request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a normal route just like with HTTP which will set `params.route` with `fieldName`:

```
return this.app.service('service-name/something').find({}).then(response => {
  console.log('data from server', response.data); // ignore this console format
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Will set `{ params: { route: { fieldName: 'something' } } }`